# sed :add a column to a file with two values

Tags: sed

I need to a add a column (the same values) with a column name to a already existing tab-delimited file.
I don't want to create a new file etc.

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

I need a new Column with a header Z containing only one value 2 across all rows.

```
A B C D Z
1 5 1 2 2
0 6 1 0 2
```

How can I do it with sed?

My idea was `sed "1i Z" | sed "s/$/&\t2/"`. But 1li adds a header of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most simply:

```
sed '1 s/$/\tZ/; 1! s/$/\t2/' filename
```

Since the data is strictly tab-separated, I could also see this done with awk:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR == 1 { $(NF + 1) = "Z" } NR > 1 { $(NF + 1) = 2 } 1' filename
```

One could argue that this is conceptually cleaner. In the end, both do the same thing, though.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>unless there is an empty line, in which case the awk version will just write the new field into the line rather than a tab followed by the new field.